# Plagiarism at its worst

Tags: masters

A fellow student I vaguely know asked to see my assignments, I figured for format idea! She then took it and submitted it or them as her own! Professor wants to penalize me! Is it fair???

Comment: This seems more like a complaint than a legitimate question (i.e., no specifics given or requests for recommended course of action). No, it's not fair. Talk to your professor, appeal the decision, show evidence that it was your original work, show the timestamps on files, etc.

Comment: My professor wants to reduce my mark! I worked super hard on the assignment and only showed it to fellow student after she pressured me! Thought i was only helping her get an idea of what it needed to entail! Why am I being penalized? Other student gave an excuse of having sent the wrong file! Does this make sense?

Comment: Big lessons to learn here: don’t show your work, friends are not always friends, people lie... And I’m sad you had to find out like this...

Comment: As somebody who has been on the teacher's side of this all too many times: accept that your teacher cannot divine that you were the original author and not the other student. Consequently, the onus is on you to provide convincing evidence that the work was originally yours. A friendly, honest conversation where you show clearly that you intimately understand your work (whereas your "friend" probably does not) and understanding that sending the assignment was a mistake in the first place goes a very long way. Complaining and talking about unfairness probably does not get you anywhere.

Comment: @xLeitix At my university, our code of conduct stresses "don't help others cheat" as much as it stresses "don't cheat". We wouldn't really care who was the original author. It depends on the local rules and policies, but proving that you originally wrote the assignment might not be the get-out-of-jail-free card you claim it is.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden The same for every university I have ever taught at, but in practice most teachers are *much* more lenient towards the enabler than towards the cheater, especially if they see how they made a mistake.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden In this instance, it seems that the OP didn't intend to help others cheat. The OP merely tried to help another student, which should be encouraged. Unfortunately, they helped a dishonest student who cheated them.

Answer (score 5):

*Is it fair?* That depends, what are the rules? If the rules forbid you from showing fellow students your work, then you've broken the rules and you are being fairly punished, otherwise, you might be being punished unfairly. Regardless, speak to your professor.